# How to get angle of view on a windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, camera, angle

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8 and it requires the angle of view of the camera of the device.

Is there any way to get the angle of view either programmatically or some API for camera.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gyroscope for that or use a [Motion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.sensors.motion%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) API.

Check this article for more details [How to use the combined Motion API for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202984%28v=vs.105%29.aspx);